# vim missing #include suggestions

Tags: vim

I was unable to find following vim completer feature. Say you write a code and you specify a type before including appropriate header file defining this type e.g.:

```
int main(){
    uint8_t a = 0, b = 5;
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

What you end up with is:

```
use of undeclared identifier 'uint8_t'
```

warning in VIM (I use YouCompleteMe) and a compilation error:

```
error: unknown type name ‘uint8_t’
```

What I'm looking for is a completer that suggests you something like

```
use of undeclared identifier 'uint8_t' did you include stdint.h?
```

If no such feature exists so far, what is the reason?

Comment: *"If no such feature exists so far, what is the reason?"* What problem would such feature solve? If you are missing identifier declaration, you know to look for missing header. This is not an issue for programmers.

Comment: You probably need to look in the YouCompleteMe literature instead of vim.

Comment: How would the editor know without parsing all include files? Adding the fact that some types are built-in to the compiler. And what's the problem seeing the error when compiling?

Comment: Sometimes I use a type and I don't remember the headers in which it is declared that's all. An automatic lookup utility I would say

Comment: And how would the editor know without knowing about the header? You have an XY problem. Use a naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) I had a [small feature](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/ftplugin/c/c_AddInclude.vim), that given a ctags database will be able to add the inclusion statement related to the symbol under the cursor. Now I've extracted the [feature](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-dev/blob/master/plugin/add_import.vim) to [lh-dev](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-dev).

I also remember to have defined an [associative map](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/autoload/lh/cpp/types.vim) that knows where a few symbols from the standard library come from, so far I only use it to automatically add the inclusion statement for types we inherit from in my C++ class snippets. What is sure, is that it could also be used for fixing missing includes (not everybody want to parse the standard library with ctags).

Note however, my scripts don't try to automatically detect all missing includes to add them. It's much too complex in real C++ projects.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add directory path to the `-I` option list of your compiler, or add the directory path to VIM's path option variable

```
:help 'path
```

If you don't know wich path to include, `locate stdint.h` could be a good start.

Related [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407565/disabling-vims-location-list-on-missing-c-header-file).

Comment: `stdint.h` is a C99 standard header. We are not expected to do anything with `-I`.